# iPhone SIGSEGV crash with any level of Optimization using ARC+ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: optimization, crash, automatic-ref-counting, asihttprequest, segmentation-fault

1. I currently use ASIHTTPRequest for synchronous requests
2. I recently refactored my code to comply with ARC and omit the ASIHTTPRequest class using the compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc`
3. I have a `_mh_execute_header` SIGSEGV crash when I use any type of optimization

While turning off all optimization allows my app to run - I need to be able to optimize the app using the iOS default settings which use `Fastest, Smallest [-Os]`

Since this is a memory related issue and since the only manually managed memory resides within ASIHTTPRequest - is using ASI with ARC my problem?

Stack Trace:

```
Thread: Unknown Name (Crashed)
    0     libobjc.A.dylib                     0x37b9ef7e objc_msgSend + 21
    1     Test                          0x000dcda5 _mh_execute_header + 126373
    2     Test                          0x000dc4b9 _mh_execute_header + 124089
    3     Test                          0x000cd801 _mh_execute_header + 63489
    4     Test                          0x000ce39d _mh_execute_header + 66461
    5     Test                          0x000cf561 _mh_execute_header + 71009
    6     Test                          0x000d3e3d _mh_execute_header + 89661
    7     UIKit                               0x3334ccbd -[UITextField keyboardInput:shouldInsertText:isMarkedText:] + 148
    8     UIKit                               0x3334cc1f -[UIFieldEditor keyboardInput:shouldInsertText:isMarkedText:] + 94
    9     UIKit                               0x3334cbb9 -[UIKeyboardImpl callShouldInsertText:] + 108
    10   UIKit                               0x3334bb5b -[UIKeyboardImpl addInputString:fromVariantKey:] + 114
    11   UIKit                               0x3334bae1 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleStringInput:fromVariantKey:] + 164
    12   UIKit                               0x3334a775 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:] + 1320
    13   UIKit                               0x334e48a3 -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar sendStringAction:forKey:isPopupVariant:] + 486
    14   UIKit                               0x33348dcd -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar touchUp:] + 3196
    15   UIKit                               0x333480fd -[UIKeyboardLayout touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 380
    16   UIKit                               0x3324b92b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 318
    17   UIKit                               0x3324b319 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 380
    18   UIKit                               0x33231695 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
    19   UIKit                               0x33230f3b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5826
    20   GraphicsServices                    0x373f022b PurpleEventCallback + 882
    21   CoreFoundation                      0x357d1523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38
    22   CoreFoundation                      0x357d14c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140
    23   CoreFoundation                      0x357d0313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1370
    24   CoreFoundation                      0x357534a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
    25   CoreFoundation                      0x3575336d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    26   GraphicsServices                    0x373ef439 GSEventRunModal + 136
    27   UIKit                               0x3325fcd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
    28   Test                          0x000bfc1b _mh_execute_header + 7195
```

Comment: Update: Apple apparently doesn't care what the optimization level is so this became more of a question about technical debt. Since my app will remain small, it is no longer as much of a concern.