# SIGSEGV Crash on iOS TestFlight Device

Tags: iphone, ios, segmentation-fault, ad-hoc-distribution, testflight

I have a weird crash which only happens on TestFlight ad hoc distributions. I know what's causing the crash (a simple while loop, see below), but I don't understand why it doesn't crash on my simulator nor iPhone or iPad (with a development profile).

I'm constantly distributing adhoc builds to trace the crash, but I've finally given up. How can I trace this bug more efficiently?

Here's the TestFlight crash report:

```
    Exception reason

SIGSEGV

Stacktrace

PRIMARY THREAD THREAD 0

0 Meernotes 0x0019649a testflight_backtrace + 158
1 Meernotes 0x001970c4 TFSignalHandler + 244
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32d9d7ec _sigtramp + 48
3 libobjc.A.dylib 0x37d34eac _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 224
4 libobjc.A.dylib 0x37d34eac _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 224
5 libobjc.A.dylib 0x37d34dc8 _objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 12
6 CoreFoundation 0x358e1cfe _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 18
7 UIKit 0x333d5c92 _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler + 42
8 CoreFoundation 0x35965b1a __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
9 CoreFoundation 0x35963d56 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 258
10 CoreFoundation 0x359640b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 760
11 CoreFoundation 0x358e74a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
12 CoreFoundation 0x358e736c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
13 GraphicsServices 0x37583438 GSEventRunModal + 136
14 UIKit 0x333f3cd4 UIApplicationMain + 1080
15 Meernotes 0x000850da main (main.m:16)
16 Meernotes 0x0008508f start + 39
```

And here is the code which is triggering it (but which is fine on simulator/iphone):

```
        while (textStillFits) {

        textToBeKeptBeforeCutting = textToBeKept;
        textToBeMovedBeforeCutting = textToBeMoved;

        rangeCutOffPosition = [settings determineFirstCutOffRangeOfString:textToBeMoved];
        textToBeKeptTemp = [textToBeMoved substringToIndex:rangeCutOffPosition.location];
        textToBeMovedTemp = [textToBeMoved substringFromIndex:rangeCutOffPosition.location];
        textToBeMoved = textToBeMovedTemp;
        textToBeKept = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", textToBeKept, textToBeKeptTemp];
        NSUInteger l = [settings linesOfText:textToBeKept];
        if (l > maxLines) {
            textStillFits = NO;
            textToBeKept = textToBeKeptBeforeCutting;
            textToBeMoved = textToBeMovedBeforeCutting;
            // brakes here!
        }else {
            textStillFits = YES;
        }
    }
```

I had a look at this, but it didn't help: [ad hoc iphone sigsegv crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060211/ad-hoc-iphone-sigsegv-crash-while-debug-on-device-simulator-works)

Some more context, as @ott mentioned that NSNotFound may cause this:

```
    -(NSRange)determineFirstCutOffRangeOfString:(NSString *)s {

    NSRange rangeSpace = [s rangeOfString:@" " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange rangeReturn = [s rangeOfString:@"\n" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (rangeSpace.location == NSNotFound && rangeReturn.location == NSNotFound) {
        rangeSpace = NSMakeRange(1, 0); // don't take 0,0 as this will lead to endless loop
        rangeReturn = NSMakeRange(1, 0);
        NSLog(@"NEITHER SPACE NOR RETURN FOUND");
    }

    NSRange rangeCutOffPosition = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
    if (rangeSpace.location < rangeReturn.location) {
        // i.e. if the space char is the lowest char where you can cut off
        rangeCutOffPosition = NSMakeRange(rangeSpace.location+1,0); // +1, i.e. always cut off AFTER the space
    }  else {
        // i.e. if the return char is the lowest char where you can cut off
        rangeCutOffPosition = NSMakeRange(rangeReturn.location+1,0); // +1, i.e. always cut off AFTER the return
    }

    return rangeCutOffPosition;
}
```

Comment: Could it be that `rangeCutOffPosition` becomes something like `NotFound`? The device is usually more picky where the simulator just ignores it. Can you insert some NSLog()'s to see what's going on, or step thru it.

Comment: @ott I always init NSRange rangeCutOffPosition = NSMakeRange(0, 0); so it cannot be NSNotFound. However, I have some methods prior to this to check some other ranges and this may return NSNotFound. But how can this be a problem?

Comment: @ott I provided some more code context above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this using ARC or manual reference counting?

Answer (score 0):

Their latest [sdk 1.2.4](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/download/) fixes this issue!